# Rename a Hyper-V VM Network Adapter using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm trying to rename a Network Adapter on a virtual machine in Hyper-V. I've read through the [documentation on MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848457(v=wps.630).aspx) and the `Set-VMNetworkAdapter` cmdlet has a parameter `-Name<String>` which reads:

> Specifies the name for the virtual network adapter. The cmdlet changes the name to the value that you specify.

Which suggests to me that I should be able to name a Network Adapter as whatever I put in for the String.

Yet when I try the line:

```
Set-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName 'CENTOS' -VMNetworkAdapterName 'Network Adapter' -Name 'eth0'
```

I get an error:

```
Set-VMNetworkAdapter : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Name' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3".
```

Am I misunderstanding the use of the `-Name` parameter? Or am I simply misusing the CMDlet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you could use the "Rename-VMNetworkAdapter" cmdlet. :)

```
Rename-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName 'CENTOS' -Name 'Network Adapter' -NewName 'eth0' -WhatIf
```

Comment: Thanks, no idea how I missed that! I could have saved myself an hour!

Comment: @Spellchamp Been there, done that... Not with this particular scenario but other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you look lower down from the documentation you are quoting you would see that `-Name` is an alias for `-VMNetworkAdapterName`. Therefore you are already trying to name it 'Network Adapter' in your code sample.

So the error is indeed correct in stating that the parameter is specified more than once.